# Chrome extension: how to call sync request from onBeforeRequest function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to intercept request to the mysite.com. Then I want to get through api.service.com actual mirror of mysite.com.

**manifest.json**:

```
{
    "name": "InterceptMySite",
    "version": "0.1",
    "description": "My first Chrome extension",
    "permissions": ["webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "cookies",
                    "*://mysite.com/*", "*://api.service.com/*"],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },

    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**background.js**:

```
var mirror_url = false;
function setMirrorUrl() {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', 'http://api.service.com', false); // sync request
    req.send(null);
    req.onload = function() {
        mirror_url = this.getResponseHeader('Mirror-Url');
    }
    return mirror_url;
}
function getMirrorUrl() {
    chrome.cookies.get({url:'http://api.service.com',name:'mirror_url'}, function(cookie) {
        if ( ! cookie)
            return setMirrorUrl();
        else
            return cookie.value;
    });
}
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(info) {
        if(info.url.indexOf('api.service.com') != -1)
            return {cancel:false};

        getMirrorUrl();

        return {redirectUrl: info.url.replace(/mysite.com/i, mirror_url)};
    },
    // filters
    {
        urls: [
            "*://mysite.com/*",
            "*://api.service.com/*"
        ]
    },
    // extraInfoSpec
    ["blocking"]
);
```

API returns mirror URL in the custom response header 'Mirror-Url' (body of response is empty). Also API stores mirror URL to the cookie "mirror_url" with expiration time after 3 hours from now.

In the second and subsequent intercepted requests to the mysite.com all works fine: mysite.com URL replaced by actual mirror URL stored in the cookies.

But in the first request to the mysite.com (when there is no cookie with mirror url) host URL replaced by "undefined" because onBeforeRequest listener returns redirectUrl **before** getMirrorUrl() is finished. Why? XMLHttpRequest object (in the **setMirrorUrl()** function) set to the **sync** request.

Answer (score 0):

Because the the `setMirrorUrl` function does some async work, when the function returns the AJAX request has yet to be made, so when you call the `setMirrorUrl` function mirror_url is false then with the function you do some async work and still return false out of the function. The solution here is to make you own functions synchronous as well.

Even though the HTTP request is synchronous, the call to the onload function is still asynchronous.

Try something like this.

```
    function setMirrorUrl(callback) {
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open('GET', 'http://api.service.com', false); // sync request
        req.send(null);
        req.onload = function() {
            callback(this.getResponseHeader('Mirror-Url'));
        }
    }
    function getMirrorUrl(callback) {
        chrome.cookies.get({url:'http://api.service.com',name:'mirror_url'}, function(cookie) {
            if ( ! cookie)
                return setMirrorUrl(callback);
            else
                return callback(cookie.value);
        });
    }
    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
        function(info) {
            if(info.url.indexOf('api.service.com') != -1)
                return {cancel:false};

            getMirrorUrl(function(mirror_url){

                return {redirectUrl: info.url.replace(/mysite.com/i, mirror_url)};

            });

        },
        // filters
        {
            urls: [
                "*://mysite.com/*",
                "*://api.service.com/*"
            ]
        },
        // extraInfoSpec
        ["blocking"]
    );
```

Comment: hmmm... Now I get correct mirror_url variable inside **getMirrorUrl()** function, but... now it doesn't affect to onBeforeRequest listener function. Even if I change getMirrorUrl return to "return {cancel:true}" - nothing happened

Comment: onBeforeRequest listener completed before getMirrorUrl() finished

Comment: Yes I can see that, you're dealing with matters that are all asynchronious, so you need to send callbacks in to all function's in order to get the correct behavior. So don't rely on return values, rely on callbacks, this is the standard way of dealing with these sort of things in javascript.